# Are "gadfly" and "gadabout" related?

Tags: etymology, vocabulary

A recent question prompted the answer of ***"gadabout"*** - which made me think of ***"gadfly"***.

Are the two related? If so, which gave rise to the other; or, did they occur contemporaneously? What's a "gad"?

Comment: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gadfly http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gadabout  http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=gad

Comment: The OED lists 'gad' as a verb meaning to ramble or wander, eg. to gad about. Hence a gadabout, a person who wanders or gads about.
However, the word 'gad-fly' comes from the noun, gad, which is a sharp spike. Presumably the gadfly's sting was like a spike. It is also possible that gadfly comes from the verb gad, ie. a fly which wanders about.

Comment: I hope that you do add some research to your question, to justify overruling the close vote. As my answer details, the connection between the two words is (or was a century ago) more controversial than a quick scan of Etymology Online's discussion might suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Summary (paraphrased from [Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=g&p=0&allowed_in_frame=0)): **Gadfly** probably comes from gad (n), a goad, but "the sense is entangled with gad (v) 'rove about'".  **Gadabout** comes from gad (v) plus about.  The noun, gad, is older than the verb, gad (from gadden); both are older than gadfly. (The verb gad may perhaps be derived from the noun gad.) Gadabout is comparatively recent. More complete etymologies follow.

[Etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?l=g&p=0&allowed_in_frame=0)

> **gadfly** (n.) also gad-fly, 1620s, "fly which bites cattle," probably from **gad (n.)** "goad, metal rod," here in the sense of
>   "stinger;" but the sense is entangled with **gad (v.)** "rove about"
>   (on the notion, perhaps, of the insect's power of flight or of the
>   restlessness of animals plagued by them), and another early meaning of
>   gadfly was "someone who likes to go about, often stopping here and
>   there" (1610s). Sense of "one who irritates another" is from 1640s
>
> **gad** **(n)** c. 1300, "a goad, sharp pointed stick to drive oxen, etc.;" c. 1400, "sharp-pointed metal spike," from Old Norse gaddr
>   "spike, nail," from Proto-Germanic *gadaz "pointed stick"......
>
> **gad** **(v)** mid-15c., gadden, "go quickly, hurry," of uncertain origin, perhaps from gad (n.) "sharp stick for driving oxen" on the
>   notion of moving as animals do when being driven by a gad.
>
> **gadabout** (n.) "one who gads or walks idly about, especially from motives of curiosity or gossip" [Century Dictionary], 1830; see **gad
>   (v.)** + about (adv.). As an adjective from 1817.....

(Emphasis added to definitions for clarity.)

Answer (score 2):

Ernest Weekley, *An Etymological Dictionary of Modern English* (1921) gives no indication that the terms *gadabout* and *gadfly* use *gad-* in an etymologically shared sense. Here are Weekley's entries for the the relevant terms (I omit his coverage of *gad* in the sense of "God," as in *gadzooks*):

> **gad<sup>1</sup>**. Spike. O[ld] N[orse] *gaddr*, spike, nail, associated with the unrelated A[nglo-]S[axon] *gād*, goad. Hence *gad-fly*. With quot[ation] [see below] cf. *spur of the moment*. [Example:] All this was done/Upon the gad (*Lear*, i. 2).
>
> ...
>
> **gad<sup>3</sup>**. To wander aimlessly. Back-formation from obs[olete] *gadling*, A[nglo-]S[axon] *gœdeling*, comrade, cogn[ate] with *gather*. In M[iddle] E[nglish] this meant base fellow and in 16 cent[ury] vagabond. For *gad-about* cf. earlier *gadder about* (N[ew] E[nglish] D[ictionary] 1568).

Unlike Etymology Online, Weekley sees an association between the Old Norse word for *spike* and the Anglo-Saxon word for *goad*, but no crossover between the those senses of *gad* and *gad* as a short form of *gadling* meaning aimless wandering. In reaching this conclusion, Weekley seems to break intentionally from Walter Skeat, [*An Etymological Dictionary of the English Language*](https://archive.org/stream/etymologicaldict00skeauoft#page/n5/mode/2up) (1888), whose work he clearly consulted. Skeat has two entries for *gad*:

> **GAD** (1) a wedge of steel, goad (Scand[inavian]) 'A *gad* of steel;' Titus Andron[icus] iv. 1. 103. Also 'upon the gad,' i.e. upon the goad, suddenly; K[ing] Lear, i. 2. 26. '*Gadde* of steele, quarreau dacier;' Palsgrave. M[iddle] E[nglish] *gad*, a goad or whip; 'bondemen with her *gaddes*' = husbandmen with their goads or whips; Havelok, 1016. **—** Icel[andic] *gaddr* (for *gasdr*), a goad, spike, sting, cognate with E. *goad*, *yard*. See **Goad**, **Yard**. Der[ived term] *gad-fly*, i.e. sting-fly; and see *gad* (2).
>
> **GAD** (2), to ramble idly. (Scand[inavian]) 'Where have you been *gadding*?' Romeo [and Juliet], iv. 2. 16. '*Gadde* abrode, *vagari*;' Levins, 7. 47. The orig[inal] sense was to drive, or drive about. **—** Icel[andic] *gaddr*, a goad. See above. I see no connection with M[iddle] E[nglish] *gadeling*, an associate, fir which see **Gather**.

So if you follow Skeat (1888), *gadfly* and *gadabout* share a Scandinavian ancestor equivalent to Icelandic *gaddr*; but if you follow Weekley (1921), the two words derive from fundamentally unrelated precursors to the coincidentally same syllable *gad*.

---

As a side-note, Thomas Wright, [*A Dictionary of Obsolete and Provincial English*](https://books.google.com/books?id=qvAIAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA692&dq=%22Nanny+hen%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=f13DVLfoEJfeoAT3qIGQCA&ved=0CD4Q6AEwAg#v=snippet&q=%22Gad%20%281%29%22&f=false) (1857) lists nine meanings of *gad* (not including "to wander aimlessly"), as well as meanings for *gad-about* ("A rambler"), *gader* ("To gather"), *gading/gadding* ("A going about; a pilgrimmage"), and *gadling* ("A worthless vagabond").

Answer (score 1):

"Late 16th century: from gad1, or obsolete gad ‘goad, spike’, from Old Norse gaddr, of Germanic origin; related to yard1." -- gadfly. Dictionary.com. Dictionary.com Unabridged. Random House, Inc. http://www.dictionary.com/browse/gadfly (accessed: April 30, 2016).

Is the etymology give for the 'gad' in 'gadfly'. I would suggest that to goad or to be spiky in countenance is very similar to what a gadabout might do, so I would suggest that some common ancestry is likely, though I could find not sources for 'gadfly' regarding the word original. At a guess: yes, they do have common origin... probably.